# sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.tutecircle.wordapp/databases/chumma", &handle, 1, NULL) failed

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to use an existing sqlite database in my android app.
I've created my database using this [link](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) and then I placed my database in

> "..../assets/databases" folder.

This is my DataBaseHelper class' constructor:

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {    
            super(context,  dbName , null, 3);
            this. applicationContext  = context;
            dbPath="/data/data/com.tutecircle.wordapp/databases/";
}
```

I tried whether the db is present or not using this code:

```
public boolean checkDataBase(){  
            File dbFile = new File( dbPath +  dbName);  
            return dbFile.exists();
}
```

the above function returns there is no database and error I got:

> sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.tutecircle.wordapp/databases/chumma",
>   &handle, 1, NULL) failed
>   sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source
>   line 25502

This is how I call:

```
 DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
 try { myDbHelper.copyDataBase();
 myDbHelper.openDataBase();
 }catch(SQLException sqle){
 throw sqle; 
}
```

This is copyDataBase function:

```
public void copyDataBase(){
 try{ InputStream assestDB = context.getAssets().open(dbName); 
OutputStream appDB = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH,true); 
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 int length; 
while ((length = assestDB.read(buffer)) > 0) {
 appDB.write(buffer, 0, length); 
} 
appDB.flush(); 
appDB.close();
 assestDB.close();
 }catch(IOException e)
{ 
e.printStackTrace(); 
} }
```

My open database function:

```
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{ 

if(databaseExist()){ 
Log.i("Db existing","db existing....");
 String myPath = DB_PATH + dbName; 
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); Log.i("Db opened","db opened....");
} 
else 
Log.i("Db not existing","db not existing...."); 
}
```

Please guys I really don't know what to do. plss help me...

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you copied the database from your assets folder to

> /data/data/com.tutecircle.wordapp/databases/

before instantiating your `DatabaseHelper`:

```
//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

//Close the streams
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();
```

EDIT: After you've updated your question it looks like that you are trying to instantiate the `FileOutputStream` in your `copyDataBase()` method with an directory rather than a path to a file. Try the following:

```
InputStream assestDB = context.getAssets().open(dbName); 
OutputStream appDB = new FileOutputStream(new File(DB_PATH,dbName));
```

Comment: Is this correct: (This is how I call):  DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
       
  try {
   myDbHelper.copyDataBase();
   myDbHelper.openDataBase();
   
  }catch(SQLException sqle){
   throw sqle;
  }

Comment: This is copyDataBase function: public void copyDataBase(){
      try{
          InputStream assestDB = context.getAssets().open(dbName);

          OutputStream appDB = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH,true);

          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int length;
          while ((length = assestDB.read(buffer)) > 0) {
              appDB.write(buffer, 0, length);
          }
          appDB.flush();
          appDB.close();
          assestDB.close();
       }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

Comment: My open database function: public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
         //if(databaseExist()){
             Log.i("Db existing","db existing....");
             String myPath = DB_PATH + dbName;
             myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
             Log.i("Db opened","db opened....");
         //}
         //else
         // Log.i("Db not existing","db not existing....");
     }